# High Precision NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, precision-and-accuracy

Define the integrand (as a function of two variables $x$ and $y$):

```
        integrand = -((64 (1 - x)^(7/2) (Sqrt[x] Sqrt[y] Sqrt[1 - x y] (-3 + 2 x y) (-1 + 4x y) - 3 ArcSin[Sqrt[x] Sqrt[y]]) HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 4, 89/20}, {5/2, 109/20}, x])/(1869 \[Pi]^(3/2) x^2 y^(11/10) (1 - x y)^(5/2)))
```

I am trying to do the following numerical integral

```
    nint[prec_] :=  NIntegrate[integrand, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> prec] // Timing
```

For instance, at precision 10 I get:

```
 In[985]:= nint[10]

Out[985]= {12.3328, 0.08959551665}
```

I would like to get as much precision as possible, ideally around 40 digits. Sadly, the problem currently scales really badly as I increase the WorkingPrecision. For instance, WorkingPrecision=20 required 3349 seconds. Also, I do not think I am actually getting as many digits of precision as the Working precision, as the WorkingPrecision=20 matches the WorkingPrecision=10 result up to 6 digits, not 10 as I might have hoped.

Are they any tricks to improve the precision, or the speed of the integral? I would be happy to run the integral overnight or even several days, if that would get me to 40 digits.

Comment: `PrecisionGoal` (and `AccuracyGoal`) control the precision of the result. `WorkingPrecision` mitigates round-off error. By default, raising `WorkingPrecision` in turn raises `PrecisionGoal`.  Generally you need `WorkingPrecision` to be a bit bigger than `PrecisionGoal` to make sure round-off error is not overwhelming truncation error.  Often the `PrecisionGoal` is set to half of `WorkingPrecision`. Multidimensional integrals might be different.  Anyway, 6 digits is about the most I would expect from `WorkingPrecision -> 10`.

Comment: Thank you! my goal is to get much higher precision tho...

Comment: You're welcome! This suggests why the integral takes so long: `Plot[(1 - x)^(3/2) HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 4, 89/20}, {5/2, 109/20}, x], {x, 0.99, 1}]`

Comment: So i ran the integral overnight for various choices of WorkingPrecision=30,40, and AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal of 20,30,40. Suprisingly, all choices gave the exact same answer to 50 digits. They also all gave the error message :

Comment: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations... Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 0.0895945516197634465248680347441 and 1.4866509405158290205766 10^{-14}    for the integral and error estimates.

Comment: So i suspect that only the first 14 or so digits are accurate. is it safe to increase MaxErrorIncreases? Or should I just try even bigger precision? Or is there some way to take into account the cancellation of the divergence fo the Hypergeometric with the zero of the (1-x)^{3/2} that occurs at x=1 as you pointed out? One option would be to write the Hypergeometric in its integral form, so that the integrand would look simpler, but then there would be 3 integrals.

Comment: "WorkingPrecision=20 required 3349 seconds" Only 1858.06 seconds here, result 0.089594551619763859052. Notice how it is different after 0.08959.